# PubNub and Multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, real-time, pubnub, livechat

I'm making an app that will use PubNub for a group chat part of the app. I turned on `Playback` on my app and I completed the tutorial for setting up the code. I'm confused though, because all the code was in the `AppDelegate`, and I have my chat view controller as part of my storyboard. My question is, what setup code do I have to do in my view controller so I can get all the past 100 messages using the `historyForChannel:start:end:limit:withCompletion:` method. Would I have to make a new instance of the PubNub client? That doesn't make sense since the user will be switching view controllers and It should be stored in a long life property.

What setup code do I have to do in my view controllers to get the past messages? (To be loaded into a very elaborate tableview setup)

Comment: Wow, as I posted this the ad that came up was for a real time chat app framework/api. There are so many!

Comment: Definitely many options but none come close to PubNub - of course I am biased but that doesn't mean I'm wrong ;) Stay tuned for an answer to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out a working solution. First, you have to make the PubNub client property public by defining it in the `AppDelegate.h` file, not the `.m` implementation.

```
// AppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <PubNub/PubNub.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, PNObjectEventListener>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

// Stores reference on PubNub client to make sure what it won't be released.
@property (nonatomic) PubNub *pnClient;

@end
```

And don't forget to delete from the `AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
/*
// Stores reference on PubNub client to make sure what it won't be released.
@property (nonatomic) PubNub *pnClient;    
*/ // Delete from here
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
```

If you want to do notifications and such, keep the `AppDelegate` as a listener to the `[self.pnClient]` property. If not, just delete `<PNObjectEventListener>` from the `AppDelegate.h` and `[self.pnClient addListener:self];` from your `AppDelegate.m`. If you prefer to keep it, just don't delete that stuff.

Now, `#import` your `AppDelegate` in your `ChatViewController.h` or the `.m` of you prefer. Then, make your `.h` conform to the `<PNObjectEventListener>` delegate. The, before you forget, add another client in your `.h` or `.m` to store the property of your PubNub client in your `AppDelegate`. :

```
// Stores reference on PubNub client to make sure what it won't be released.
    @property (nonatomic) PubNub *pnClient;
```

Next, in your `viewDidLoad` method, add:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

self.pnClient = appDelegate.pnClient;

[self.pnClient addListener:self];
```

This code first grabs the `AppDelegate` of your app, (so there are no shared instance or singleton things involved). Then, It sets the `pnClient` of your app delegate to your "temporary" client in your view controller. (See why we moved the `AppDelegate`'s client to the .h?) And lastly, it adds self as a listener, so you can do stuff in your view controller.

Thats all there is to it!

I would suggest using your chat controller to populate a UITableView or something else, and the `AppDelegate` for handling notifications.